# After system update getting error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

I have been tried most off solutions given for above error but i am not able to connect mysql server. It had been working before my ubuntu system update.

Comment: How u r using mysql ..? Standalone or with xampp/wampp..

Comment: I am using mysql standalone

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, The mysql library update stucks. That is why mysql server updating process not be completing.

When i check command "ps aux | grep mysql", i got process list of mysql update stuck processing as in given below image
[click here to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPOqW.png)

So, when i killed those both processes(pid=6728 and 7041), I am able to connect mysql server easily.